# my code keeps showing me this error 404: the current path,get, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

this is my code
I don't know where the error is coming from. It is telling me that
Using the URLconf defined in ehiz.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
add/ [name='add']
The current path, get, didn't match any of these.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
return render(request,'base.html',{'name':'Gael'})

def add(request):

val1 = int(request.GET['num1'])
val2 = int(request.GET['num2'])

res = val1 + val2

return render(request, 'result.html',{'result':res})
```

base.html

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>hello {{name}}</h1>

<form action="get">
<input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="Enter first number"><br>

<input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="enter second number"><br>

<input type="submit">


</form>


{% endblock %}
```

result.html

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}

the result is : {{result}}

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('',views.home,name='home'),
path('add/',views.add,name='add')
]
```

Comment: You likely mean `method="get"`, not `action="get"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<form>` you are confusing the `method="…"` with the `action="…"` attribute. The `method="…"` specifies the HTTP request type, whereas the `action="…"` specifies to what endpoint the request will be submitted.

You thus should work with:

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'add' %}">
    <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="Enter first number"><be>
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="enter second number"><be>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The `method="get"` is not necessary, since by default a form will be submitted through a GET request.